# Excel: DataModel - why it returns cartesian product?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpivot, cartesian-product, datamodel

Can't understand how `DataModel` works in `Excel`.
Please help

**Example:**
in `Excel` - why it returns cartesian product?
[image]

At the same time absolutely the same `DataModel` in `PowerBi` returns normal estimated result:
[image]

**Download** `Excel` file [**here**](https://github.com/DenisSipchenko/Power-BI/blob/c05bd0b85adc91856d1bc532422c041827aa6818/Questions/DataModel%20in%20Excel.xlsx)

Comment: There is no relationship between dimTable.PK and factTable.FK in the Excel example.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov, 2nd screen shows relationship in excel. If it's wrong, how to set it up in a right way?

Comment: You have to add a value field to the pivot table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just should drop something to `Values` section in pivot table:
[image]

P.S. Special Thanks to [@Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76587612/6165594) for the help!